# Can't install clamav dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, synaptic, clamav

Turns out I can't install anything using aptitude and I also seem to be missing a few dependencies.

**When I try to install a program**:

```
mom@mom-Inspiron-1720:~$ sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clamav-daemon : Depends: clamav-base (= 0.98.5+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 clamav-freshclam : Depends: clamav-base (>= 0.98.5+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
mom@mom-Inspiron-1720:~$
```

**When I use `apt-get -f install`:**

```
mom@mom-Inspiron-1720:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  clamav-base clamav-daemon
Suggested packages:
  daemon clamav-docs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  clamav-base
The following packages will be upgraded:
  clamav-daemon
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 106 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/244 kB of archives.
After this operation, 369 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Can't exec "/tmp/clamav-base.config.0YwBEj": Permission denied at /usr/share/perl/5.18/IPC/Open3.pm line 173.
open2: exec of /tmp/clamav-base.config.0YwBEj configure  failed at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/ConfModule.pm line 59.
(Reading database ... 304306 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../clamav-daemon_0.98.5+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb ...
/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon: 164: export: Default:: bad variable name
invoke-rc.d: initscript clamav-daemon, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon: 164: export: Default:: bad variable name
invoke-rc.d: initscript clamav-daemon, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/clamav-daemon_0.98.5+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon: 164: export: Default:: bad variable name
invoke-rc.d: initscript clamav-daemon, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../clamav-base_0.98.5+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking clamav-base (0.98.5+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/clamav-base_0.98.5+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man5/clamd.conf.5.gz', which is also in package clamav-daemon 0.98.4+dfsg-2~ubuntu14.04.1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/clamav-daemon_0.98.5+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/clamav-base_0.98.5+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
mom@mom-Inspiron-1720:~$
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by removing clamav - `sudo apt-get purge clamav*` - then try again.
It appears there's an error in the clamav setup at present. You could try re-installing it again after - I'd recommend purge over remove here as the error could be in config files which remove may leave behind.